# LSTM print gradients keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to print the gradients and I have this so far.

```
my_model=load_model('word2vec_lstm.h5')

weights = my_model.weights # weight tensors

gradients = my_model.optimizer.get_gradients(my_model.total_loss, weights) # gradient tensors

input_tensors = [my_model.inputs[0], # input data
                 my_model.sample_weights[0], # sample weights
                 my_model.targets[0], # labels
                 K.learning_phase(), # train or test mode
]

get_gradients = K.function(inputs=input_tensors, outputs=gradients)

inputs = [[trainDataVecs], # X input data
          [1], # sample weights
          [Y_train], # y labels
          0.005 # learning phase in TEST mode
]

print [a for a in zip(weights, get_gradients(inputs))]
```

However, this gives me the following error `InvalidArgumentError: transpose expects a vector of size 4. But input(1) is a vector of size 3`

Comment: Could you paste the entire error message?

Comment: @KevinFang This is the entire error message: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: transpose expects a vector of size 4. But input(1) is a vector of size 3
  [[Node: bidirectional_1/transpose = Transpose[T=DT_FLOAT, Tperm=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@gradients/AddN_19"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_1/embedding_lookup, gradients/bidirectional_1/transpose_grad/InvertPermutation)]]`

Comment: @KevinFang Someone had similar issue https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp/issues/288 which was solved but I am not sure how

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach to get gradients of RNN models (i.e. LSTM). Install the lib called `see-rnn` from [here](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/see-rnn).

This lib allows you to get RNN weights, gradients, & activations visualization in Keras & TensorFlow.

**Installation**

```
pip install see-rnn
```

**Example**

```
all_grads = get_gradients(rnn_model, layer_index, x, y)
print(all_grads[0][0]) 

#output: array([ 0.00116622, -0.00739232, -0.00163304, -0.00379695,  0.0126757 ,
       -0.01117346], dtype=float32)
```